# Randomly Sample in Python with certain distirbution

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe with two columns an id column which repeats the ids 1-100 3 times and then 'age' where I randomly sample the ages 0-14 17% of the time, ages 15-64 65% of the time,  ages 65-100 18% of the time.

**Example DF:**

```
id  age
1   21
1   21
1   21
2   45
2   45
2   45
3   64
3   64
3   64
```

Code i have so far:

```
N = 100
R = 3
d = {'id': np.repeat(np.arange(1, N + 1), R)}
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I'm stuck on how to simulate the age though.
How can I do this?

Comment: With "% of the time" you mean for each 100 records ?

Comment: Each id will appear 3 times, for each Id i want to sample based on that distribution. So for each distinct id there will only be one distinct age based on that distribution i specified

Comment: your ids are repeated, so according yo your previous comment you also would expect a repeated ages

Comment: Yes each age would be repeated for each id

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) for your specific ranges and thresholds:

```
df['ages'] = np.repeat(np.concatenate([np.random.randint(0, 14, 17),
                                       np.random.randint(15, 64, 65),
                                       np.random.randint(65, 100, 18)]), R)
print(df)
```

If needed, the concatenated arrays can be additionally shuffled with `np.random.shuffle` (before the *ages* would be repeated `np.repeat`):

```
ages = np.concatenate([np.random.randint(0, 14, 17),
                        np.random.randint(15, 64, 65),
                        np.random.randint(65, 100, 18)])
np.random.shuffle(ages)
df['ages'] = np.repeat(ages, R)
```

---

```
      id  ages
0      1    11
1      1    11
2      1    11
3      2     3
4      2     3
5      2     3
6      3    12
7      3    12
8      3    12
9      4     8
10     4     8
11     4     8
12     5    10
13     5    10
14     5    10
..   ...   ...
285   96    70
286   96    70
287   96    70
288   97    83
289   97    83
290   97    83
291   98    70
292   98    70
293   98    70
294   99    98
295   99    98
296   99    98
297  100    92
298  100    92
299  100    92
```

Comment: I like this solution. How can I shuffle and then use repeat over it with one line of code? When I use np.random.shuffle and wrap it in np.repeat is returns None objects

Comment: Yeah i was wondering if this could be written out in one line of code, but i guess not with the limitation of np.random.shuffle()?

Comment: `np.random.shuffle` changes array in-place. There is `np.random.permutation` which makes a shuffled copy of the array

Answer (score 0):

I suggst this method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ids = np.repeat(range(1, 101), 3)

age_choices = [(np.arange(0, 15), 0.17), (np.arange(15, 65), 0.65), (np.arange(65, 101), 0.18)]
ages = np.concatenate([np.random.choice(choice[0], size=int(len(ids)*choice[1]), replace=True) for choice in age_choices])

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids, 'age': ages})

print(df.head(30))
```

which gives

```
   id  age
0    1    2
1    1   13
2    1    8
3    2   14
4    2    0
5    2   14
6    3    7
7    3    6
8    3    9
9    4   13
10   4    9
11   4    6
12   5    7
13   5    6
14   5   12
15   6   12
16   6    4
17   6    2
18   7    0
19   7   10
20   7    4
21   8   10
22   8    8
23   8    1
24   9   10
25   9    5
26   9   13
27  10    8
28  10   13
29  10    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100
R = 3

ids = np.arange(1, N + 1)

# Assuming max age of 99
possible_ages = np.arange(100)
sizes = np.array([16, 50, 34])
percentages = np.array([17, 65, 18])

ages = np.random.choice(possible_ages, size=N, p=np.repeat(percentages / sizes / 100, sizes))

df = pd.DataFrame({
   "id": np.repeat(ids, R),
   "age": np.repeat(ages, R)
})
```

Alternatively you could sample the age group using your specified percentages first, then uniformly sample from the obtained group after.